# Encoding PDF to Base64 string and using Node.js Buffer.from() results in broken file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, base64, backblaze

I have a frontend where users can upload documents (PDFs). It converts these PDFs to a Base64 string and then sends it to a microservice where it is uploaded to Backblaze B2. This method works fine when uploading e.g. a `.jpg` file, but when trying it with a `.pdf` file it doesn't let me open it when browsing files on Backblaze's website:

[image]

So here is my frontend code:

```
export const toBase64 = (file: File | Blob) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  });

...

const base64String = await toBase64(acceptedFiles[index]);
onSelectFile(base64String as string);
```

and here is my backend code:

```
const { base64String, fileName } = request.body.input;

const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(
  base64String.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf);base64,/, ""),
  "base64"
);

const getUploadUrlResponse = await b2.getUploadUrl({
  bucketId: process.env.BACKBLAZE_BUCKET_ID || "bucketId",
});

const uploadFileResponse = await b2.uploadFile({
  uploadUrl: getUploadUrlResponse.data.uploadUrl,
  uploadAuthToken: getUploadUrlResponse.data.authorizationToken,
  fileName: fileName,
  data: fileBuffer,
  mime: "application/pdf",
});
```

As I said, this works fine when uploading a .jpg, but results in "failed to load PDF document" when using a .pdf. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix this.

Comment: Isn't pdf's mimetype `application/pdf`? Your `.replace()` is trying to replace `image/pdf`. I'm surprised `.from()` isn't throwing an exception on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this

```
base64String.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, "")
```

instead of

```
base64String.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|pdf);base64,/, "")
```

works.